# Dynamic webview height issue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview

i have a VC in which on top i have a view under it i have placed a webview in which i'm loading data from URL, under the webview there is another view. Now i'm trying to make dynamic height of webview according to content inside it. It's height works fine but when i scroll the VC it scroll till webview content and does not show view under it. My view looks like this,
[enter image description here](http://vid.us/qas8i8)

I'm making webview dynamic height like this,

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled=false;

   webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
        self.webViewHeight.constant = height as! CGFloat
        //self.bgViewHeight.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height + 500
    })
}
```

It works fine but when i scroll VC it does not show view under it.
This is how VC looks when i run the app,
[enter link description here](http://vid.us/qas8i8)

Comment: Did you get any constraints warning in console?

Comment: No i haven't had any constraint warning in my VC. @SahilManchanda

Comment: please check the video link i have added in question . @SahilManchanda

Comment: Seems like scrollview is not able to calculate contentSize automatically, Please check your constraints inside scroll view such that all the child views are properly aligned from top to bottom.

Comment: I have placed a scroll view and a view under it and all the other views and web view under it. @SahilManchanda

Comment: If possible can you email me the project so that i can look into it

Comment: please share ur email . @SahilManchanda

Comment: sahil.manchanda2@gmail.com

Comment: send to u please check it out, i'm waiting for ur response. @SahilManchanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked your code. There were two issues

1. You had given static height to scroll view's child.
2. last view's bottom constraint wasn't connected to bottom of superview.

What I've done:

1. Attached last constraint to bottom of Scroll View
2. removed the total height constraint
3. Reattached the webview constraint and assigned it's height in your evaluateJavaScript method.